# text to G-code converter

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm curious, is there a text to G-Code converter? Something where I could type a string, and get G-Code output that a 3D printer, or CNC machine could understand?

Comment: There's online stuff: http://microtechstelladata.com/OnlineTools.aspx

Comment: This is really too broad to be answered here, but no, not really. A string itself has no information about dimensions. It's just some text. You'd need to specify at least the volume for the text to occupy. There are tools to take an SVG or Blender file of your text, and extrapolate it to g-code, though.

Comment: There's this, I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, though. http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Simple_LinuxCNC_G-Code_Generators

Comment: See also this list: http://replicat.org/generators

Answer (score 1):

G-code program lists are actually text files. The output of a post processor is a text file. That file is then loaded into a control memory, and executed with that control's cycle start button.
So, are you looking for an app that will output a line of g-code given another input (conversational)? Or an open source CAM system? CAM systems are the standard tool for creating tool path, but there is a learning curve if you've never used one. It is possible to work in a text editor and create templates of your most common program structures that would give a base program that could be edited for specific situations.